# Cloudways Hosting - application shows Website Unavailable

Tags: nginx, hosting, cloudways

Website Unavailable
The website you are trying to reach is unavailable because it use security service to prevent unauthorized access and online attack.

No information in the Cloudways KB - a broad search returned nothing so I'm adding this here for others.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hosting provider says: This is a new security feature that is recently added to avoid domain mapping attacks on the websites so server will not serve a website if the domain name is not present in the Nginx domain relevant file.

To fix, in your cloudways hosting account:

Choose the application experiencing the error message

1. Choose ‘Domain Management’
2. Make sure ‘primary domain’ value is set, if it IS, (as it was in my case), change it and change it back - I added the www. to mine then went back to my preferred domain name without the www. That fixed it for me.

Comment: thanks for putting this here, this scenario just happened to me out of nowhere! so frustrating that they don't document it anywhere!!?? Its essentially making sure that all your domains have both the non-www and a www e.g. www.mysite.com & mysite.com.